# Angular 7 RxJs - HTTP calls do not complete in ForkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, fork-join

I am trying to combine a number of HTTP requests using RxJs `forkJoin`.  When I subscribe to the observable, the HTTP calls are made but nothing is returned.  I have tried replacing the HTTP calls with generic observables (`of('hello')`) and the subscription receives the results.

It appears that the HTTP calls are not 'completing' but looking at DevTools, I see the requests (response 200) and their responding data.

```
  test() {
    const simple = [
      of('Hello'),
      of('World'),
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    ];

    forkJoin(simple)
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log("Test", {result});
      }, (err) => {
        console.warn("Test Error", {err});
      });
  }
```

If I comment out the HTTP call, I get the following logged to the console:
`Test { result: ["Hello", "World"] }`

But with the HTTP call, nothing is logged to the console.

Finally - I have checked the HTTP call with the following:

```
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log('checking', {result});
      });
```

And it successfully logs the result to the console.

**UPDATE**
I have traced the issue to our HttpInterceptor which adds an Authorization header.  The interceptor relies on the AuthService for the JWT token and AuthService has to wait until the ConfigService retrieves the app configuration from a remote JSON file.

NOTE: Since the ConfigService has to make an HTTP request, we have configured the interceptor to just pass the request on if the Authorization header has already been set.  This way, we can fake the Authorization header in ConfigService bypassing the HttpInterceptor attempt to add the JWT.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthTokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (request.headers.has(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY)) {
      // do not try to add authorization header
      const dup = request.clone();
      return next.handle(dup);
    }

    // else
    return this.authService.ready$()
      .pipe(
        filter((ready: boolean) => !!ready),
        switchMap((ready: boolean) => {
          if (ready) {
            const clone = request.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
              }
            });
            return next.handle(clone);
          }

          // else ... filter should only pass when ready === true
          console.warn('OOPS -> TokenInterceptor could not add the authorization token as the AuthService was not ready');
        })
      );
  }
}
```

The AuthService's ready$ property:

```
  ready$() {
    return !!this.configService.ready$ ? this.configService.ready$ : of(false);
  }
```

And the ConfigService's ready$ property:

```
  private _config: IConfig;
  private readySubject = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();
  ready$: Observable<boolean>;
  ...
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.ready$ = this.readySubject.asObservable();
    this.readySubject.next(!!this._config);
  }
  ...
  load() {
    const fakeAuth = new HttpHeaders().set(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY, 'faked');

    return this.http.get(this.CONFIG_URL, { headers: fakeAuth })
      .pipe(
        map((result) => {
          this._config = {...DefaultConfig, ...result as IConfig};
          return this._config;
        }),
        tap(() => {
          this.readySubject.next(!!this._config);
        })
      );
  }
```

If I modify the forkJoin test() so the HTTP request has an Authorization header, the HTTP request completes and the forkJoin completes.

```
  test() {
    const fakeAuth = new HttpHeaders().set(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY, 'faked');

    const simple = [
      of('Hello'),
      of('World'),
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', { headers: fakeAuth })
    ];

    forkJoin(simple)
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log("Test", {result});
      }, (err) => {
        console.warn("Test Error", {err});
      });
  }
```

Thus, it appears that the problem is in my HttpInterceptor and/or in the logic I use to determine when the AuthService and ConfigService are 'ready'.

Perhaps this is too vague, but does anyone see a problem in the way I am handling the HttpInterceptor (and AuthService, ConfigService)?

**WORKAROUND**

I was able to find a workaround...  The problem appears to be when I return an observable in the HttpInterceptor: `return this.authService.ready$()...`

So I have created a flag (property) in the AuthService that is set to true when the service is ready to provide the JWT token.  So now, the HttpInterceptor looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthTokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (request.headers.has(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY)) {
      // do not try to add authorization header
      const dup = request.clone();
      return next.handle(dup);
    }

    if (this.authService.ready) {
      const clone = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
        }
      });
      return next.handle(clone);
    }

    // else
    console.warn("AuthTokenInterceptorService - waiting for AuthService to be ready...", {ready: this.authService.ready});

    return this.authService.ready$()
      .pipe(
        filter((ready: boolean) => !!ready),
        switchMap((ready: boolean) => {
          if (ready) {
            const clone = request.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
              }
            });
            return next.handle(clone);
          }

          // else ... filter should only pass when ready === true
          console.warn('OOPS -> TokenInterceptor could not add the authorization token as the AuthService was not ready');
        })
      );
  }
}
```

All routes that require HTTP requests with an Authorization header are protected with an AuthGuard which ensures that the AuthService is ready before canActivate is true.  Thus, the HttpInterceptor will be using the AuthService that has already been initialized (ready === true).

This seems like a hack since the HttpInterceptor is relying on the AuthGuard, so if anyone has a better implementation of the HttpInterceptor, I would love to hear it.  THANKS

Comment: Can you reproduce on stackblitz?

Comment: I just built a quick stackblitz and this code worked for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stgdrj It logged an array of 3 items.

Comment: That is strange.  The method (test()) is called from a constructor in a service.  I will try to reproduce on stackblitz...

Comment: Works when called from a service: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qf9v6n Tomorrow, I will port more of the code over to try to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

It would probably work better if you were to get your configuration during Angular's initialization process. See [Completely external constants in Angular 5 using some configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903083/completely-external-constants-in-angular-5-using-some-configuration-file/49912967#49912967)

Comment: Thanks @GreyBeardedGeek.  I do have get my config during initialization but kept the ready$ observable "just in case".  I have been using my workaround (assuming the config service has initialized) and have not found a situation when the ready$ observable is needed. I appreciate (as will others) your link for configuring the app during initialization.